# What to call the large containers of bottled water?

Tags: vocabulary

The water drawn from those 2.5 gallon containers having a spigot (and air hole) is called ‘bottled water’, but what should we call those large containers of water? It seems like “tank” or “tankard” are the best 2 choices. I am partial to ‘tankard’, as ‘tank’ seems to imply something much larger, on the order of at least tens of gallons. However, according to the dictionary, a tankard is merely a large drinking vessel. Is it possible / plausible to extend the meaning of ‘tankard’ to mean ‘large container of bottled water having a spigot and air hole’?

Comment: Are you referring to this? : https://www.google.it/search?q=big+bottled+water+con&safe=off&biw=768&bih=909&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=RPeXVeC9OYWa7Abwu5qwBA&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#imgrc=xpVF4kYZi3tPFM%3A

Comment: In most contexts (a [hot water tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_water_storage_tank) or [car fuel tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_tank), for example) a ***tank*** is a *refillable* container. OED says the definition of ***tankard*** as *large open tub-like vessel, usually of wood hooped with iron, etc.* is obsolete (the surviving definition is a drinking vessel, as you say). Why would you think that's a suitable candidate?

Comment: I call these containers *jugs*, though that term applies even better to the one-gallon container with a handle.

Comment: Those are just bottles.

Comment: Please use images.

Comment: Tankard is totally wrong.

Comment: The suppliers of the pictured items call them bottles.

Comment: OK, so let's just pretend for a minute that the OP doesn't want to call them "bottles," - for *whatever* reason - what would be a suitable, second-choice for these containers?

Comment: "OK, so let's just pretend for a minute that the OP doesn't want to call them "bottles,""  Why would we do that?  the OP will be delighted to discover that **they are called bottles**.  With crystal clarity, the OP asks (twice) what do you call the things **bottled water** comes in (in the large size).  Answer: **bottles**.

Comment: (The OP also asks an incidental question about the OP's own guess "tankards" - which is trivially dismissed.)

Comment: Each picture shows a **5 gallon** bottle of water.

Comment: The above images do NOT depict what I am talking about. It's not a water cooler situation, but a draw from the spigot from the cask sitting on the kitchen counter situation when we want to make coffee, etc.

Comment: I can't help but be amused by how happy the water supplier guy is.

Comment: *Jugs* has always been my preferred word...

Comment: A tankard is a drinking vessel made out of metal. Most tankards are either half pint or 1 pint (approx 300ml and 600 ml) though there may be some quart  (2 pint, approx 1.2 litres) ones. A water cooler bottle certainly is _not_ a tankard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, a word in clarification**: "bottles" would be the term I would naturally use for these containers. However, after using that same word - not once, but three times - the OP asks for another term. That is the nature of this OP.

So, as a second-choice, rather than *tankard* (its Middle English origins notwithstanding), perhaps a suitable term would be **cask**? While it's true that casks lack the bottle's characteristic *neck*, which is really the only feature distinguishing one from the other, cask would seem a viable second-choice

> [**bottle**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bottle) *noun*:
>   **1 a**: a rigid or semi-rigid container typically of glass or plastic having a comparatively narrow neck or mouth and usually no handle. (Merriam-Webster online)
>
> [**cask**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=cask+definition&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=cask+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0j0i7i30l4.0.0.2.537956...........0.yfp1sfu6Exs&gws_rd=ssl) *noun*: a large barrel-like container made of wood, metal, or ***plastic***, used for storing liquids, typically alcoholic drinks.
>
> *synonyms*: barrel, keg, butt, tun, vat, drum, hogshead; *historical* firkin; "*casks* of ale for the crew" (Google)
>
> [**tankard**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/tankard) *noun*: **1**. a tall beer mug, typically made of silver or pewter, with a handle and sometimes a hinged lid.
>
> *Origin*: Middle English (denoting a large tub for carrying liquid): perhaps related to Dutch *tanckaert*. (Oxford Dictionaries *online*)

Comment: Yes, I think ‘cask’ is the word of choice. (However, does this mean that the one-gallon containers will come to be called ‘caskettes’, and, finally, ‘caskets’?)

Comment: Good one, @EsperantoSpeaker1  :-)

Comment: [Casks](https://www.google.com/search?q=cask&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=hjeYVfrNA8ijgwSRqoCoDg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAQ&biw=1280&bih=890) are for alcohol and tankards are what you drink it from. If I asked what's in the cask and it was water, I'd be disappointed.

Comment: @Mazura - sorry to disappoint you. We needn't be bound by the typical. I think a plastic "cask" could effectively carry water and is a serviceable term here.

Comment: I'm afraid "cask" is totally wrong.  Eva, are you familiar with the things being described?  Quite simply, **those are not barrel-like** and have utterly no connection to kegs, butts, tuns, vats, drums, etc.  Note that the bottles in question **have necks at the top** and are a totally different family from drums, casks, barrels.

Comment: "However, after using that same word - not once, but twice" (Actually zero times.)

Comment: incidental issue: *"While it's true that casks lack the bottle's characteristic neck, which is really the only feature distinguishing one from the other"* I fear that would be like saying the 'only thing' distinguishing a teacup from a coke bottle is the size of the opening, heh!

Comment: @Joe Blow - my bad. The author of this question, EsperantoSpeaker1, actually uses the term “bottled,” the past tense of the verb “bottle,” on three separate occasions. According to Merriam-Webster, "bottled" means: to confine as if in a bottle. So, my assumption is that the OP has a passing familiarity with the noun and verb “bottle.” Perhaps I’m wrong. Maybe EsperantoSpeaker1 will clarify.

Comment: No, "bottled water" is a thing.  i,e not tap water, more like mineral water.

Comment: You've got me there @Joe Blow.

Answer (score 11):

I think you are looking for a ***carboy*** or a ***demijohn***. They are usually made of glass but they can be plastic also. For commercial use, they usually contain distilled water and they can be used in households.

> A carboy or demijohn is a rigid container with a typical capacity of 20 to 60 L (5 to 15 gallons). Carboys are primarily used for transporting liquids, often water or chemicals. [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carboy)

---

<sub>Carboy is from Persian *qarāba* large flagon (for wine, rose water, etc.; of uncertain origin, perhaps related to Arabic *qirba* large leather bottle, water-skin)<sup>OED</sup></sub>

<sub>Demijohn is from French *dame-jeanne* (1694 Th. Corneille *dame-jane*, 1701 Furetière *Dame Jeanne*, lit. ‘Dame Jane’)<sup>OED</sup></sub>

---

**Note:** The picture is added later to the question and I would like to add some further details. Water delivery companies call them *bottled-water* mostly but OP wanted to differentiate from smaller or larger containers. Carboys and demijohns have the capacity level that OP is asking for and they are used for water delivery/storage. Although, they might not be prevalent in everyday usage and might be more prevalent in industrial usage. These containers have other usages also. For example, they can be used as a fermenter in homebrewing.

From the book *[Homebrewing For Dummies](https://books.google.ca/books?id=OWwCXEZJ-u8C&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=water%20delivery%20carboy&source=bl&ots=i7Fuzbkiom&sig=XXOMz5ANwyuIgpQziTEzO3AwxdA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_DWZVYGZONKhyATY3YKgDA&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=water%20delivery%20carboy&f=false)* By Marty Nachel:

> Carboys are large cylindrical jugs that water delivery companies used for years until they switched to the plastic carboys today.

Comment: I'm afraid this is completely wrong.  While it is erudite and admirable to point out that carboy, demijohn are cool historical (and perhaps, say, scientific) words for "large bottles" ... I encourage to find **even one reference to the water delivery bottles in question, on the 4.54 billion pages of the internet**

Comment: @JoeBlow: You didn't search enough and OP wanted to differentiate from smaller or larger containers. These containers have the capacity level that OP is asking for. Although, they might not be prevalent in everyday usage and might be more prevalent in industrial usage. Naturally you can just call it "bottled water" of course but OP has details.

Comment: @JoeBlow: One of the many references: https://books.google.ca/books?id=OWwCXEZJ-u8C&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=water+delivery+carboy&source=bl&ots=i7Fuzbkiom&sig=XXOMz5ANwyuIgpQziTEzO3AwxdA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_DWZVYGZONKhyATY3YKgDA&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=water%20delivery%20carboy&f=false

Comment: outstanding reference, good one.  but it is in a beer brewing context.  you won't find Culligan, as it were, calling them anything but bottles (or maybe just "containers")...

Comment: @JoeBlow: https://www.google.ca/search?q=water+delivery+demijohn&biw=1252&bih=602&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=tl-ZVe3MPMeCyQS_oYrIAw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=water++carboy

Comment: Hi Em -- right, every single reference on that search is of this nature... Let's look at the first one: **"The office water jug is technically a “carboy” though most people outside the homebrewing world won’t recognize the word."**.

Comment: BTW you're astute to call it an "industrial" word (I said "archaic" or "perhaps scientific").

Comment: @JoeBlow: I already said that it is not prevalent in everyday usage but it is what it is and that is the name of that type of bottle. You are the one who is misleading and wrong from the beginning.

Comment: I appreciate your adding “carboy” and “demijohn” to my vocabulary, but they won’t work for the scenario I am alluding to: I am walking down the aisle, at Tom Thumb, with my SO and two rug rats and say, “Hold on a second, we need to get a couple ___.” Formerly, I would have filled in the blank with “tank” or “tankard”, but now with “cask”. No way am I going to fill in that blank with “carboy” or “demijohn”, and certainly not - since it has a spigot - with “bottle”.

Answer (score 5):

They are **bottles**, exactly as Chasly points out.  You can so trivially find 100,000 usages on the internet, it is not worth making a link here.

Note that your best bet is probably to refer to them as:

## "water delivery bottles"

or perhaps better

## "water cooler bottles"

That would be the most absolutely clear way to refer to them.

Consider propane/cng bottles which are a similar size. It's true that propane/cng "tanks" are so-called in some English-speaking regions - but they are propane/cng "bottles" in others.  The water cooler bottles to which you refer, OP, are much more bottle-like than cng-bottles ... the water cooler bottles are completely bottle-like topologically, with a neck and open mouth and so on ... so I think you would struggle to call them "tanks".  As Fumble astutely notes, tanks are refillable things. {Indeed, you only "get away with" calling cng bottles 'tanks', rather than 'bottles', for that very reason, I feel.}

Finally I direct you to tchrist's comment. "Those are just bottles."  It's that simple.

Comment: "Bottles" would be the term I would naturally use also. However, after using that same word - not once, but twice - the OP asks for another term. That's the point of this OP. And Joe, all the bolded text, screaming "bottles, bottles" is unnecessary. I feel fairly confident that the vast majority of us realized, long before you posted this answer that "bottles" was the natural term for such containers, so it seems we are suggesting alternatives. Try to relax Joe, you're scaring me.

Comment: Hi Eva!  If you interpret "bold" or "large" letters on screen as "screaming" or another vocal or social analogue - well, **it's your life to LIVE as you CHOOSE!"**  Good luck with that!  :) Note that the OP does not, even once, use the word "bottle".  The OP refers to them as "large containers of water".  (Feel free to delete or edit your comment to avoid ongoing confusion.)  Glossing over it, you may have spotted the two "bottled water" references (one in quotes) from the OP, causing the confusion. Cont...

Comment: Also, the OP does not at all ask for "another term".  Note that, even if the OP had mentioned "bottle", it's commonplace on SWRs that a user asks 'what do I call word X?' - and the answer is "in fact, you call it word X".  Again, I mention this purely as a unrelated issue.  The OP is asking for the word for the thing bottled water in that size cometh in.

Comment: Regarding your more general vibe, why am I emphatically over and over, uh, emphasizing the answer?  This web site is often really amazingly confused.  (Example at hand.)  Often the only hope is to, in a word, repeat something - say - about seven times.

Comment: @LittleEva this is a restrained answer from Joe! It's positively held back in chains, muffled and gagged compared to some of his more colourful posts. Although I have to say the [*It's that simple*](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A8286+%22that+simple%22) catchphrase is wearing thin on me. :))

Comment: @Mari-Lou - an altogether inspiring character, no?

Comment: @LittleEva There is room for this type of answer, as long as it is respectful, sometimes a post which breaks the EL&U mould is refreshing. *Sometimes*...

Comment: BTW, in my answer I "hashtag" the single line of text that shows the actual answer to the SWR in question.  (in this case, I suppose they are "supplementary suggestions", as the answer, "bottle", was already given.) This is the correct and good use of the "hashtag" large letters line. I encourage everyone in SWR answers - SWRs generally being a weird beast - **to put the actual solution you are suggesting in large case like that using the hash**. In this way one can flick through, and avoid the staggering amount of fluff almost always found on SWRs.

Answer (score 3):

If the plastic or glass container comes with a tap or spigot, it can be called: a ***drink*** or [**beverage dispenser**](https://www.google.it/search?q=Beverage+Dispenser&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=6vObVczoCMHkUqfNn6AL&ved=0CCEQsAQ&biw=1366&bih=653). The capacity  of the containers is usually mentioned, such as: “a 3-gallon beverage dispenser” (with or without the hyphen).  [**Barrel beverage dispensers**](https://www.google.it/search?q=Beverage%20Dispenser&es_sm=122&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=6vObVczoCMHkUqfNn6AL&ved=0CCEQsAQ&biw=1366&bih=653#tbm=isch&q=barrel%20Beverage%20Dispenser) needn't be wooden nor have to be filled with alcohol.

[image] [image]

A **5-gallon water dispenser** is a plastic jug that contains bottled water. **Without the spigot** (or tap) they are just called (1.5/3/5/10 gallon) **[water bottle](https://www.google.it/search?q=10%20gallon%20water%20dispenser&es_sm=122&biw=1366&bih=653&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=hrqcVZ23IsL9UKalpcgL&sqi=2&ved=0CCcQsAQ#tbm=isch&q=gallon%20%22water%20bottle%22&tbas=0)**.
[image][image]

**[Rain barrels](https://www.google.it/search?q=5%20gallon%20faucet&es_sm=122&biw=1366&bih=653&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=ZvabVff2CYv_UMn0gpgL&ved=0CDkQsAQ#tbm=isch&q=%22rain%20barrels%22)** or **rainwater tanks** are large containers, often made of plastic, for collecting and storing rainwater that run from rooftops.

[image]

Comment: “dispenser” is good, and so I’m upvoting your answer,  but “cask” is better, being only one syllable. So, if someone doesn’t understand “cask”, then my plan B is to use “dispenser”.

Answer (score 2):

These are called jugs of water. See foe example the 3 and 5 gallon jugs here: http://tulpehockenwater.com/products.asp

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @deadrat jug of water is what these are called.

Comment: Possibly.  But you said that's what *you* have always called them that.  I've always called them clear-round-plastic thingies.  Which of us should the innocent believe?  Certainly they fit the definition of "jug," but is there a term of art or common slang usage in the bottled-water business?

Answer (score 1):

In the trade they call them bottles.  Maybe flagon or pitcher.

Comment: Indeed - note that bottles of propane, CNG etc - which are that same size - are indeed just called "bottles".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flagon and http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/flagon

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to these,

[**Link to picture**](http://previews.123rf.com/images/NewAge/NewAge0809/NewAge080900004/3533354-Large-bottle-of-purified-drinking-water-on-white-Stock-Photo.jpg)

These are called 'gallons' in our local shops. Haven't heard of any other name elsewhere till date (though they might exist).

**https://www.google.co.in/search?q=water+gallon** will also give you these.

Note: Gallon also refers to these:

[**Link to picture**](http://5c66e53e70f99ca62de4-b9cf175ae397b1f6ec307e00a3d10107.r11.cf5.rackcdn.com/B003.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I would call them " xx liter bottles". Even jug and pitcher are lesser known than bottles. Everyone know what a bottle is. Go ask a three year old which word they know best. That will be the best one.

The best word or the most accurate should only be the one  that most people agree on not what dictionary says is accurate (well unless everyone else around you is English professor).

Comment: I agree with you first sentence. The important part is its capacity; call it whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would add to this.
I am a service tech for a water company. (New Zealand)

We call them bottles. Our stock code is H2O15 (H2O 15 ltr). We also call them WD bottles (Water delivery) or FYO Bottles (Fill you own) The US people call them Water cooler jugs.

Answer (score -1):

Jerry can? I think jerry can or jerrycan/jerrican maybe a good alternative to large plastic bottle... It's a particular shape of course similar to some of the pictures posted here.